# What is the difference between test of independence and test of randomness in linear regression?

Tags: regression, independence, assumptions

In section 3.3 of Kutner's Applied Statistical Linear Models:

> **Nonindependence of Error Terms**

> Whenever data are obtained in a time sequence or some other type of sequence, such as
> for adjacent geographic areas, it is a good idea to prepare a sequence plot of the residuals.

> ...
> When the error terms are independent, we expect the residuals in a sequence plot to
> fluctuate in a more or less random pattern around the base line 0. ...

In section 3.4

> **Tests for Randomness**

> A runs test is frequently used to test for lack of randomness in the residuals arranged in time
> order. Another test, specifically designed for lack of randomness in least squares residuals,
> is the Durbin-Watson test. This test is discussed in Chapter 12.

What is the difference of testing independence of error terms and testing of randomness in the residuals? I guess they are the same thing?

Comment: They're both testing independence against dependence, but in different ways. DW explicitly tests lag 1 autocorrelation, the runs test is somewhat sensitive to that, but also responds to other forms of dependence. It's a bit like comparing a Jarque Bera test against a Shapiro-Francia test when you're interested in normality; they both are tests of normality against non-normality, but they respond differently to different aspects of non-normality. If you're *specifically* interested in what a more specific test looks for, that's a good thing, otherwise it might not be.

Comment: Thanks, @Glen_b! Is test for non-correlatedness viewed as a kind of test of randomness?

Comment: While it's not usually referred to that way, obviously it is the case - clearly if its rejected the data are dependent.